# Localizar linha que se inicie com negação da expressão

Tags: regex, sublime-text

Eu possuo um arquivo de texto com muitas linhas. É possível eu encontrar a primeira linha que não case com a `regex`? Exemplo, quero fazer uma regex que me mostre a primeira linha que não comece com BOLO

BOLO
BOLO
*CHOCOLATE*

Estou usando o `sublime`, ou seja, minha `regex` tem que achar a palavra CHOCOLATE. Lembrando que minha `regex` precisa ser em cima da palavra BOLO porque não sei qual a linha que vem após.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine a ancora (`^`) de início com o lookhead negativo (`?!`) isso vai identificar as linhas que não começam com BOLO

```
^(?!BOLO)
```

Texto:

```
BOLO
BOLO
CHOCOLATE
RECEITAS BOLO
```

Esse exemplo casa as duas últimas linhas.

Veja funcionando no [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/risEal/2)

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.